# Socket connection not closing in android in while loop

Tags: android, sockets, button, while-loop

I am developing an app where I connect via a socket to get data from the, but once I establish a socket connection invoked via a button click, I can see that I am able to connect and get the data, but the socket connection doesn't terminate and the app hangs. I have included socket.close(); in my code but it isn't helping below is my code snippet..

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            /// some code which isn't important here

            // establish socket connection to get data

              try{
                     Socket s = new Socket("IP",portnumber);
                     Log.d(TAG, "socket connected");
                     PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);                  
                     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                     out1.println(value1);
                     Log.d(TAG, value1);
                     String line="";
                     String msg = "";
                     while ((line=in.readLine()) != "//end of message from server")
                     {                   

                                 msg+=line+"\n";
                                Log.d(TAG, msg);

                     } 
                     out1.close();
                     in.close();
                     s.close();
                     Log.d(TAG, "socket closed " );
                    } 

          catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "file finished " + e.getMessage());
                 }
```

Comment: have you tried to Debug your code ?

Comment: yesI did, when the s.close(); statement is within the while loop, I get entries in my list.. else the while loop is executed and then the program just hangs within the while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It `hangs` in in.readLine();. You are waiting there for the server to send another line. But the server does not. If the server would close, readLine would return with null. But the server does not close. There are several possibilities to solve this.

For the rest: you are opening and writing a complete file for every line. Better do that only once after the while loop.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some possibilites  to check this and to write a file outside the loop? Thank you in advance

Comment: Possibilities to check this?? There are possibilities to solve this. As you are writing the server too I suppose you now know that server and client should know when the end of a message is reached. You could simply let the server send "END OF MESSAGE\n" as last line and let the client check every line for it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not writing the server side. I connect to the server via TCP and only get the data. If I put the condition to write the file till the end of message from server, the loop again is executed only once (socket connections closes) and I don't get any further or consequent entries in the file!! Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: You dit not put `File gpxfile .....` and following code lines after the while loop. Please adapt your code. Better yet: all code from `File root ...`. Leave only `msg+=...` in the loop.

Comment: For simplifying and reducing the conversation here, I commented the filewriter part. Now you can see that I only need to read message from server through the socket and the condition is it does until the end of message. But if I execute this part of the code (even after checking via debugging) I get the data, but the control doesn't come out of the while loop. This is the problem I am facing even though the condition is fine.

Comment: Well you could as well have placed it below the loop. Or yet better: remove it completely. Then we could better concentrate on the loop itself. As it is now you throw away half of the lines. You should only have one call to readLine. `String line=null; while((line=in.readLine())!=null) { msg+=line+"\n"; .....` Please adapt your code.

Comment: Removed it now and I tried, same still within the while loop :( the flow doesn't come out of it. I tried including s.close() inside while and it works for one entry and it is displayed in the console.

Comment: What is this `//end of message from server` ? Does the server really send that as last string? If the server does then you cannot check for it in this way. Check for null -as i suggested- and then in the loop `if (line.contains("//end of message from server")) break;`. Please adapt your code.

Comment: end of message is a string "EOF". I already tried it like the way you suggested last night but it didn't work. the if condition i tried was with in.readline() and msg to check for string "EOF". Is there anything wrong with the reader buffer?

Comment: Great +1.. I am working with `WebSockets` and your answer helped me alot.. as `handshake` requests and responses have empty line `""` at last.. matching which I can break the loop.